# Time required to add missing place name in Google map API

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-3

Recently, I have added 2 place's names on Google Maps and they have been approved. However, they still don't show up on [Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/).

How many days will it take to add a place and make it public?

Answer (score 0):

### Suggestion Approval

When you make a suggestion to a place, via the "[Send Feedback](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094045?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)" option on Google Maps, or using [Maps Maker](https://mapmaker.google.com/mapmaker), the suggestion needs to be approved.

This procedure **usually** takes less than 15 days.

I say **usually** because they deal with a lot of data submissions and corrections, so there could be a delay in response.

### Propagation

Once a correction has been approved, it **usually** takes two business days for it to propagate all over Google's systems and to appear on google.maps.

---

Hope it helps!